# trying to understand how Matlab's fillmissing() processes gaps when using custom fillfun

Tags: matlab

I was using Matlab's `fillmissing` function to replace missing values in some data using a custom function, and I was running into trouble filling data at the locations that I thought should be considered 'endvalues' by the function.  It's fairly clear from the documentation that the `fillfun` method uses a different moving-window definition than the `movmean` or `movmedian` methods, as they define the window on either side of each gap element, while `fillfun` processes the window on either side of each full gap.

That said, looking at the following test array, `A`, that includes several combinations of missing values that should be addressed as individual columns:

```
>> A = reshape(1:20,5,4);
>> A([1,7,8,9,11:15,20])=NaN
A =
NaN 6 NaN 16
2 NaN NaN 17
3 NaN NaN 18
4 NaN NaN 19
5 10 NaN NaN
```

Using the simple fill methods things are straightforward:

```
>> fillmissing(A, 'constant', 0)
ans =
     0     6     0    16
     2     0     0    17
     3     0     0    18
     4     0     0    19
     5    10     0     0
>> fillmissing(A, 'constant', 0, 'endvalues',99)
ans =
    99     6    99    16
     2     0    99    17
     3     0    99    18
     4     0    99    19
     5    10    99    99
```

Now if I just use a simple test function:  `@(x,y,z) z` which should fill the entire gap with the SamplePoints position (default [1 2 3 4 5]), that's when behavior gets odd:

```
>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, 2)
ans =
     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5     5

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, 2, 'endvalues',99)
ans =
    99     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5    99
```

It seems what are considered 'endvalues' are not equivalent between methods. Further, it seems `fillmissing` arbitrarily excludes endvalues (consistent with the above caveats) if the window has no included points, whether or not the function is defined to fill those values:

```
>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, [2 0])
ans =
   NaN     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5     5

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, [0 2])
ans =
     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5   NaN

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, [0 2], 'endvalues', 99)
ans =
    99     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5    99

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, [0 2], 'endvalues', 'extrap')
ans =
     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5   NaN
```

Last, the interaction with 'SamplePoints' seems unclear.

```
>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, 2, 'SamplePoints', [1 2 3 4 5])
ans =
     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5     5

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, 2, 'SamplePoints', [1 2 3 4 5]+10)
ans =
    11     6     1    16
     2    12     2    17
     3    13     3    18
     4    14     4    19
     5    10     5    15
```

That appears to maybe be a bug in the way SamplePoints is handled. Can anyone clarify expected behavior?  Am I missing something? If there is clearer documentation somewhere for this function method I would appreciate any pointers.

(Tested using Matlab 2021b if that matters. Update: verified above behavior persists in Matlab 2022b.)

(Edit: see answer below with updates showning function output changes tested in Matlab 2023a.)

Comment: i did wind up submitting some of this as a support inquiry to Mathworks, and they indicated that some of it is unexpected, although without complete detail of which parts may or may not be bugs. will update with any information gained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that as of Matlab 2023a, the inconsistencies posted above when using a custom `fillfun` with `fillmissing` have been resolved. See below:

the current output of the same commands now produces:

no changes to the simple cases:

```
>> fillmissing(A, 'constant', 0)
ans =
     0     6     0    16
     2     0     0    17
     3     0     0    18
     4     0     0    19
     5    10     0     0
>> fillmissing(A, 'constant', 0, 'endvalues',99)
ans =
    99     6    99    16
     2     0    99    17
     3     0    99    18
     4     0    99    19
     5    10    99    99
```

the `fillfun` method now consistently sees an empty column as endvalues the same as above:

```
>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, 2)

ans =

     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5     5

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, 2, 'endvalues',99)

ans =

    99     6    99    16
     2     2    99    17
     3     3    99    18
     4     4    99    19
     5    10    99    99
```

And endvalues appear to be consistently accounted for with ranges:

```
>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, [2 0])

ans =

     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5     5

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, [0 2])

ans =

     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5     5

>>  fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, [0 2], 'endvalues', 99)

ans =

    99     6    99    16
     2     2    99    17
     3     3    99    18
     4     4    99    19
     5    10    99    99

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, [0 2], 'endvalues', 'extrap')

ans =

     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5     5
```

and the SamplePoints interaction is also consistently using the actual value rather than the place-value:

```
>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, 2, 'SamplePoints', [1 2 3 4 5])

ans =

     1     6     1    16
     2     2     2    17
     3     3     3    18
     4     4     4    19
     5    10     5     5

>> fillmissing(A, @(x,y,z) z, 2, 'SamplePoints', [1 2 3 4 5]+10)

ans =

    11     6    11    16
     2    12    12    17
     3    13    13    18
     4    14    14    19
     5    10    15    15
```

Comment: Was the “2” being interpreted as the dimension, rather than the gap? Which were endpoints would make sense if it processed rows instead of columns.

Comment: I don't have the old version to test on anymore, but I don't think so. the `fillfun` method requires a `gapwindow` at the next input, and I think playing with that did what you'd expect for a windowsize not a dimension. if nothing else, that should have given an error about a mismatch in the number of elements in SamplePoints in the operating dimension. (since the 5 samplepoints only matches dim1).  it was pretty consistent catching those things.